# Adding recipient to Magento mail template

Tags: php, magento, email

I am trying to add a "send copy to me" feature to the Magento contacts form. Please see the code below. If you aren't aware, Magento takes $_POST and copies it to $post.

I have tried both ->setRecipient and ->setRecipients. I couldn't find documentation on these so I am assuming you are to just plug in the email as a variable and not an array.

$post['email'] is a basic text variable like "user@domain.com";

```
            if($post['sendmeacopy']==true){
             /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
            $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                ->setSenderEmail('no-reply@bonposh.com')
                ->setRecipients($post['email'])
                ->setReplyTo('no-reply@bonposh.com')
                ->sendTransactional(
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                    null,
                    array('data' => $postObject)
                );
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the recipients emailaddresses as third argument in `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::sendTransactional()`. This argument is passed to `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::send()` which accepts an array of emails. So an array of email recipients could be passed. No additional methods need to be called. `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template` provides a `addBCC` method, too.

Assuming `$post['email']` is an array of email addresses your code to send the same mail to different recipients could look like this:

```
 /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
$mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))                                
    ->setReplyTo('no-reply@bonposh.com')
    ->sendTransactional(
        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
        'no-reply@bonposh.com',
        $post['email'],
        null,
        array('data' => $postObject)
    );
```

Comment: Would you mind providing an example? I don't understand how I should I apply your response to fix my issue.

Comment: He suggests you to do $mailTemplate->addBCC($email)->->sendTransactional(.., .., array($email1, $email2, $email3), .., ..)->..

Comment: Thanks, exactly. I updated my answer with an example based on the provided example code.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I am just getting back around to taking care of this. The posted email was not an array, I tried converting it to one and magento still didn't want to take it. So, i opted for magalter's addBBC option. Works like a charm. Thanks!